# The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]"

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have a web application and I'm using primefaces + hibernate. When deploying my application in tomcat after a while the application crashes and shows me that there was an exception memory overflow.

I used the eclipse memory and says:

One instance of "org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoaderProxy" loaded by "Equinox Class Loader Startup" Occupies 868 520 (10.08%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object []" loaded by " class".

keywords
java.lang.Object []
Startup Equinox Class Loader
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoaderProxy

I find that kind could be that is causing the overflow.

If you could help them greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is your actual question, and what sort of research/troubleshooting have you performed already?

Comment: well, I want to find exactly what is causing the buffer overflow that causes tomcat fall.

I used the eclipse memory analizer and tell me what I mentioned earlier.
It tells me that class is causing the problem, I just said it was a java.lang.Object.

My application crashes every 8 hours by the buffer overflow.

Comment: Post the stack trace. NB 'buffer overflow' isn't the same as 'memory overflow'.